# variable undefined in python3

Tags: python

Below is the code. The variables are defined earlier in the file

```
if selc == "1":
    unitPrice = a2
elif selc == "2":
    unitPrice = b2
elif selc == "3":
    unitPrice = c2
elif selc == "4":
    unitPrice = d2
elif selc == "5":
    unitPrice = e2
print (unitPrice)
```

the terminal says that unitPrice is undefined, how can i fix this?

Comment: I don't my eyes cheat me; but your variable `unitprice` is misspelt, so it could be that. Another way is `unitPrice` wasn't declared ere the conditions were evaluated.

Comment: your'e right, some of the capitalization is off, i hope this wasn't a bad question

Comment: @JohnStivers So the issue was the capitalization?

Comment: could you further explain the second half?

Comment: @Poriferous unfortunately not

Comment: @JohnStivers What error is it giving, can you provide it to us? You also note that you create the variables earlier. Is this code in a function? It would be helpful if you give us where you define the variable, and the error that you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need some consistency with your variable names. It looks like you come from an 'old' language background (e.g. C, or Java). In Python, variables are named with underscores. So `unit_price` as opposed to CamelCase `unitPrice`.

Next, make sure that `unit_price` is always declared. There's two ways of doing this:

```
unit_price = 0
if something:
   unit_price = 1
```

Or, make sure that unit_price is always defined in your `if` block, by including and `else` block:

```
if something == 0:
    unit_price = 0
elif something == 1:
    unit_price = 1
else:
    unit_price = 2
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: haha, you are right about the java. it turns out that I should have asked the if statements to check for ints instead of Strings. It works now :)

Comment: @JohnStivers Ha, lol. That's amazing. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you copy/pasted your code, then unitPrice and unitprice are not the same. Check your capitalization.

If there is still an issue, chances are that you didn't declare the unitPrice variable above. Not 100% sure about python scope, but you most likely need to declare the variable right above the if statement.

ie

```
unitPrice = defaultValue
if selc == "1":
    unitPrice = a2
.
.
.
print(unitPrice)
```

Comment: I fixed this, and declared the variable above the statements, however it still says the same error

Comment: Your declaration of unitPrice is wrong. That does nothing.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot the initialization. Fixed.